# Dynamic unknow field in JSON

Tags: json, kotlin, dynamic, field

I'm trying to build the right classes from the following URL:

https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2020-01-01&end_date=2020-01-08&api_key=DEMO_KEY

At this moment, I have the following structure:

```
data class NearEarthObject (val asteroidObjects : Map<String, DateSelected>)
```

```
data class DateSelected (val date: ArrayList<Asteroid>) {
```

```
 data class Asteroid(
    val id: Long,
    val codename: String,
    val closeApproachDate: String,
    val absoluteMagnitude: Double,
    val estimatedDiameter: Double,
    val relativeVelocity: Double,
    val distanceFromEarth: Double,
    val isPotentiallyHazardous: Boolean
)
```

And this is my Java code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val URLAPI = Constants.BASE_URL

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        asteroidActivityRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        asteroidActivityRv.adapter = null

        val retrofitAsteroids = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URLAPI)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val apiAsteroid = retrofitAsteroids.create(ApiAsteroids::class.java)
        val callAsteroid = apiAsteroid.getAsteroids()
        callAsteroid.enqueue(object : Callback<NearEarthObject> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NearEarthObject>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.e("TAG fail", t.toString())
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<NearEarthObject>,
                response: Response<NearEarthObject>
            ) {
                for (res in response.body().asteroidObjects) {
                    // Log.e("TAG result", res.value.date)
                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

But I keep receiving the following error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Set java.util.Map.entrySet()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.nasanwsproject.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:44)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

it looks response.body().asteroidObjects==null

i think this problem because you cant receive the response use map。
it require a definite class（include the field and value。）